# CSS file not being loaded when a slash is added after the path URL

Tags: css, .htaccess

I've made a simple code to remove a `.php` extension from the URL, but when I add a slash after the file (`url.eu/file/`) it doesn't load the css I made. The CSS is only displayed when the URL looks like `url.eu/file`.

Any idea why?

```
Options +MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Can you include the relevant HTML for the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a base tag to the `<head>` section of your html.

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: It actually works, but when I add it to banlist.php, it just doesnt work so as I see it works only in the index file

Comment: Whatever your header, is where it should go. if this banlist.php file is separate, you might have to use absolute path. I'm not quite sure of this banlist.php file. Also if the main issue is fixed, [See about accepting the anwser](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308899)